# WPF Combo box not calling setter method when item changed

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box that is bound to an object from a model that is instantiated inside of my view model. `OnPropertyChange` is handled inside of the Notifier class that inherits from `INotifyPropertyChange`. The view model polls executes a method from a data access layer and returns an observablelist to the view model. This is then passed into a constructor that builds the object i want to bind to the combo box. The object has two properties. 1) An observable list of possible selections and 2) a string that represents the current selected item.

Here is the problem. The combo box is successfully bound and populated by the list. It does not however appear to call the setter method when an item is changed. I need this functionality so I can continue with application logic once the item is elected. Debugging confirms that no setter is called, only the get. The setter is in fact called on the model however which make sense. Im certain I am missing something here and am open to suggestions on a better way to do this.

**Model**

```
public class WellListGroup : Notifier
    {

        private ObservableCollection<string> _headers;

        public ObservableCollection<string> headers
        {
            get { return _headers; }
            set { _headers = value; OnPropertyChanged("headers"); }
        }

        private string _selected;

        public string selected
        {
            get { return this._selected;}
            set { this._selected = value; OnPropertyChanged("selected");}
        }

    }
```

**Notifier**

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

**View Model**

```
public class MainViewModel :  Notifier
{
    //data access layer
    public static getWells gw = new getWells();

    //set combo box
    public static ObservableCollection<string> headers = gw.getHeaders();
    private WellListGroup _wlg = new WellListGroup {headers = headers, selected = headers[0]};

    public WellListGroup wlg
    {
        get {
            return _wlg; 
        }
        set {
                _wlg = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("wlg");
                OnChange()// do stuff!!!

            }
    }
```

**View**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="groupComboBox"  
          DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
          ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = wlg.headers}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path = wlg.selected, Mode=TwoWay}">
 </ComboBox>
```

**EDIT - Reworked ViewModel to Subscribe to event on the object**

```
public class MainViewModel :  Notifier
{
    //data access layer
    public static getWells gw = new getWells();

    //set combo box
    public static List<string> headers = gw.getHeaders();


    private WellListGroup _wlg = new WellListGroup {headers = headers, selected = headers[0]};


    public WellListGroup wlg
    {
        get {
            return _wlg; 
        }
        set {


                _wlg = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("wlg");
                OnChange(_wlg.selected);// do stuff!!!

            }

    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Move this into the constructor to avoid any race conditions
        _wlg = new WellListGroup {headers = headers, selected = headers[0]};

      // Subscribe to the property change even for WLG
       _wlg.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == "selected") {

            }
                OnChange(_wlg.selected);// do stuff!!!
        };
    }
```

Comment: `wlg` is not actually being set here `wlg.selected` is being set. You could move your on `OnChanged()` to the selected set function or capture the `SelectionChanged` event on the combobox.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying here. Is there anyway to handle either of those from within the view model?

Comment: I don't think so, the combobox is selected property is what is changing, not the selected property of your model.

Comment: @LCaraway you could look into ICommand or RelayCommand [MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is that the reflected property setter is **within** the `_wlg` class and not the setter of the _wlg class itself on the VM. *The bounded item is not going to the top level but the lower property as mentioned*.

Either put in a commanding system to kick off the `OnChange()// do stuff!!!` code or subscribe to the `_wlg` class instance `INotifyProptertyChanged` event and call the method you mentioned.

---

> Is there anyway to handle either of those from within the view model?

Yes, subscribe to the instance of the class `WellListGroup` property changed event and look for `selected` or others to report a change.

```
public MainViewModel()
{
   // Move this into the constructor to avoid any race conditions
   _wlg = new WellListGroup {headers = headers, selected = headers[0]};

  // Subscribe to the property change even for WLG
   _wlg.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == 'selected')
                    OnChange()// do stuff!!!
            };
}
```

---

Of note, it is unclear if you really need to hold the strings in an `ObservableCollection`. That collection has its own implementation of notify events for adding and deleting of items within the collection.

If the VM needs that specific change info, then you will need to subscribe to the `ObservableCollection`'s event(s) for such operations instead of/as well as the aforementioned above example.

If one does not need those notifications, holding the strings in an `ObservableCollection` is not needed and you can change it to a `List<string>` instead.

Comment: I'm giving this a shot. I do not specifically need the observable collection and have changed it to list<string>. The observable collection was an earlier attempt at me trying to get this to work. Could you be more specific as to where to include the above solution. I will edit my question to show what i have changed that made sense to me. Though I am certainly still a beginner at all of this so please explain where/Why I am wrong.

Comment: I see that you placed your code inside a method with the view model name, can you explain the placement of that and how it relates to the constructor/ view model?

Comment: @LCaraway the code is an event assignment which instead of another named method it is using an inline anonymous delegate utilizing the lambda notation. You could also just create a method with the same signature in your code and it will work just fine.

Comment: In this instance do I remove the getter and setter methods? Can you review my edited code and tell me your thoughts, it appears to be working but I feel it is not exactly what you are saying. Thanks again or your help so far!

Comment: @LCaraway it looks fine to me. Keep it as it is. Having a class adhere to `INotifyPropertyChanged` even if no one subscribes to it will not significantly slow down the processing. If the future it is needed, it is already implemented.

Comment: @LCaraway Upon second look, remove the fields assignment for _wlg and leave only the one in the constructor. You are creating two of them.